# How to know the first blank cell in a column in Excel or Google Spreadsheet using only native formulas

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Suppose A2,A3,A4 are filled. A5,A6 are empty. A7-10 are filled.

Is there a way to know that A5 is the first blank cell after A2?

For example,

```
A1 | =sum(...)
A2 | 3
A3 | 4
A4 | 1
A5 |  
A6 | =sum(...)  
A7 | 2
A8 | 5
A9 | 7
A10| 10
```

What one formula may we use to replace "..." in order to sum the cells below until the next blank cell? ie. Can a formula on A1 for `sum(A2:A4)` be re-used on A6 for `sum(A7:A10)` by just copy-paste?

Here is my story of failed attempts.

So the starting row is easy to get. Just put in `A2`.
For the end row, Google Spreadsheet doesn't equate `""` with empty cell. So `sum(A2:index(match("",A2:A)))` will not work.

`isblank()` with an array input will give a single output `FALSE` regardless of the content. So `sum(A2:index(match(TRUE,isblank(A2:A))))` won't work.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: So ultimately column A will consist of a mixture of formulas in some cells and static values in others? Not good practice, I have to say. So when you paste the given formula in, how will you ensure that it only goes into the intended cells within that column? And are we to assume that A11 is also blank?

Comment: `A10` is intended to be the last occupied row. So yes `A11` is blank. The copy paste would be manual. The idea is a user can use a spreadsheet tab as multiple tables displayed together. The user can start a new table with an unknown number of rows below existing tables and obtain the same statistics like in previous tables without any additional effort except for ctrl+c&v and without formulas in previous rows breaking down.

Answer (score 6):

in order to find the first empty cell with MATCH you can do the following

=MATCH("@",ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A&"@"),0)

This is needed because MATCH doesn't work with blank cells, as you found out.

Comment: Nice work around. Thanks. What does `@` do in this case? Is that a special character? And will this formula compute when wrapped in `indirect` or `arrayformula` the same way as it does standalone?

Answer (score 2):

Asuming column headers in row 1 followed by one blank row, sample data in column A, interrupted by 1 or more blank cells ...

1. find the top row of each group in column B

   B3: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),ISBLANK(A2))`
2. build a group value in column C

   C3: `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),ISBLANK(A2)),C2+1,C2)`
3. build a conditional sum for each group in column D

   D3: `=sumif($C$3:$C$25,C3,$A$3:$A$25)`
4. combine all above in column E

   E3: `=if(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A3)),ISBLANK(A2)),sumif($C$3:$C$25,C3,$A$3:$A$25),"")`

After each step copy down the formula from row 3 until the end of the table. Mind the absolute addressing for the `SUMIF()` function.

After all this works to your satisfaction, you may throw away columns B and D, they are just for illustration how we build it up and not used in the final formula.

[image]

Comment: Clever. Pardon my ignorance. If the function in question is not a simple `sum` but an expression by compounding multiple Spreedsheet functions, is there a way to apply the expression based on value range like what you did with `sumif`?

Comment: ultimately it has to be an aggregating function (sum, count, average), otherwise the whole problem doesn't make sense, If there is a way to use the multiple spreadsheet functions already on the data in A before aggregating then I'd probably go that route, otherwise you need to be a bit more specific on what should be the outcome.

Comment: Indeed, it does have to be an aggregating function. How would `sumproduct` or `sum+count` work for example?

Answer (score 1):

In any cell you need the sum function, the range would start one row below the formula and end when the first blank cell is found ? If so this should work:

```
=sum(indirect("A"&row()+1&":A"&MIN(ArrayFormula(filter(row(indirect("A"&row()+1&":A")); indirect("A"&row()+1&":A")="")))))
```

This formula can simply be copy pasted.

Comment: What if the function question is for a simple `sum()`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
sum(A2:index(match(TRUE,isblank(A2:A))))
```

just add `arrayformula` for `isblank` so that it returns an array internally:

```
sum(A2:index(match(TRUE,ArrayFormula(isblank(A2:A)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The match formula will search a range for the first instance of a given value, but cannot match a blank cell, so we need to provide a range with some value it can match. We can do this with an arrayformula, which applies its inner formula to every cell of the range. In this case, we can use the isblank formula to return `true` for every blank cell, then match to `true`:
`=match(true,arrayformula(isblank(A2:A)),0)`

Comment: Consider using code fences "```" before and after  "```" your  answer to help set it apart from text. Describing how and why your code works is extremely helpful.